# EDID signal with DVI Splitter

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, dvi, edid

I have a computer and two monitors (with different sizes and resolutions) and I want to connect them to the PC via a DVI Splitter. My doubt is: how do you define the EDID "signal" in this setup? The splitter has a main output (which sends the EDID) and secondary (that fits)? Or EDID signal is taken by monitor with lower performance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no EDID splitter. Technically it could be possible, but it wouldn't help since the DVI connection would still obly carry one resolution/refresh rate anyways.

Splitting DVI will most likely just turn into a sad picture display on one of the monitors.

If you are wondering what happens EDID-wise: either you will get one correct EDID or none at all (or garbage). What it depends on is the DDC pins being connected or not, and to what output.

In many cases only one of the DVI connections will be connected, and the other one will just have to deal with the signal, hoping it can display and scale the input.